# Java-jre installation problem on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

For java installation on ubuntu 18.04
I made this command at the beginning:

```
sudo apt install default-jre
```

For java jre installation
after I typed

```
java -version
```

it displays

```
The command "java" was not found
```

So it is not installed but if we type again:

```
sudo apt install default_jre
```

it displays:

```
default-jre is already the most recent version (2: 1.11-68ubuntu1 ~ 18.04.1)
```

I don't understand why

How to do?

RMQ: JDK (java compiler) it installs perfect I did:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk
```

After

```
javac -version:
```

it displays the normal compiler version

```
javac 11.0.9.1
```

If possible can help me

Comment: if you get no answer try asking at https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: use this command sudo apt install default-jre
and java -version if not work restart system and check again

Comment: i already tried sudo apt install default-jre it displays: default-jre is already the most recent version i tried for restart system 
thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can install Java 8 with the following command.

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```